# Not able to search Spanish word with accent in solr

Tags: solr

I have install solr 3.5
I would like to search words(Spanish words) like
enseñé
étnico
castaño
después

with ascent ñ,é etc.

But solr is not search such words from index.
I have used

```
 <!-- Spanish -->
    <fieldType name="text_es" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer> 
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_es.txt" format="snowball" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.SpanishLightStemFilterFactory"/>
        <!-- more aggressive: <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Spanish"/> -->
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

like :

```
<field name="name" type="text_es" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="features" type="text_es" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

But still not able to search Spanish word with ascent..

Please let me know if I am missing anything?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can check with the Solr analyzer how your query and your indexed content get analyzed:

```
http://192.168.0.1:8080/solr/#/your_core_name/analysis
```

Do you simply do:

```
/select?q=name:castaño
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory) filter.

It converts characters with ascent into their no-ascent counterpart.
Put this in your schema.xml:

```
<filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
```

*Note: The downside is that words like "cañon" and "canon" are now equivalent and both hit the same documents IIRC.*

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
<fieldType name="text_es" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer> 
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_es.txt" format="snowball" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.SpanishLightStemFilterFactory"/>
        <!-- more aggressive: <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Spanish"/> -->
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

But it works with it:

```
<fieldType name="text_es" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer> 
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_es.txt" format="snowball" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
       <!--  <filter class="solr.SpanishLightStemFilterFactory"/> -->
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Spanish"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```